# Can java_library.data runtime location be changed within bazel?

Tags: bazel

On my way to migrate an existing build to bazel, i have a submodule mod1 that has some JUnit tests reading files from a "testdata" directory. When trying to load those files, i have to use "mod1/testdata/test.txt" instead of "testdata/test.txt", i.e. the unit tests have to be aware of their corresponding bazel module directory.

(1) Is this the correct behaviour for bazel 0.23.2@debian and 0.23.2-homebrew?

(2) Is there a way to use the .java tests *without changes*, and to remove the need for a "mod1" prefix in bazel data/ runfiles?

My sample project is here: https://gitlab.com/jhinrichsen/bazel-data-test. I am looking for a way to use the same path "testdata/test.txt" for both root module and submodule. In my example project, `bazel test AllTests` suceeds, while `bazel test mod1/AllTests` fails because i need to prepend "mod1/" to "testdata/test.txt".

Not looking for a resources/classpath based solution as i cannot modify the existing test sources.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior that you are seeing is indeed the correct behavior, and there is no way to strip the "mod1" prefix with the native Java rules. Anything you include with `data` will be scoped to its own package in the way you're seeing.

The reason for this is pretty straightforward. Let's say that your test target, `//mod1:AllTests`, also depended on a hypothetical `//mod2:tests` library. And let's say that hypothetical library *also* had a `testdata/test.txt` as a data dependency. The multiple `test.txt` files would conflict unless they were namespaced to their packages.

If you absolutely cannot modify the test source at all, then you are pretty much stuck. Here's a previous discussion about this:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/bazel-discuss/w6TDwSZvN0k

I would recommend if you're trying to work with Bazel, you accept the concept of runfiles and modify your tests to either work with the runfiles structure, or accept a command-line argument for where to find the test data.